# part of textfield is disapearing

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

So I have two textfields in a AS3 program.  One of them displays fine, the other one gets cut off about half way through, any idea what could have caused this?  They are created with all the same parameters (except they have different text).

Sorry about the lack of detail.

```
var tf1 = new TextField();
tf1.text = "You scored: " + score + " points";
tf1.x = miscellaneousObjects[0].x + 50;
tf1.y = miscellaneousObjects[0].y + 50;
tf1.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
tf1.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
uiTextLayer.addChild(tf1);
var tf2 = new TextField();
tf2.text = "Would you like to play again?";
tf2.x = miscellaneousObjects[0].x + 50;
tf2.y = miscellaneousObjects[0].y + 80;
tf2.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
tf2.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
uiTextLayer.addChild(tf2);
```

miscelleanousObjects[0] refers to the image of a box that's supposed to be surrounding the text.  As you can see they're created exactly the same.

Comment: Are they dynamically generated with AS3 or just controlled by script?

Comment: You would get much more specific help if you provided some example code. In general, this is a useful skill to learn -- to reduce your problem to the smallest code snippet that reproduces it.

Comment: Far too vague for anyone to answer. Surely it is not too hard to post your code for both textfields.

Comment: Same fonts ? Fonts embedded ? Are just the capitals missing ? Multi-line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textfields default to a size of 100 pixels by 100 pixels. Try explicitly setting the width of the TextField:

```
tf1.width = 500;
tf2.width = 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
tf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```